# How to save results from websocket into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, websocket

I am streaming data from a websocket into my python application successfully using these lines of code:

```
wsClient = GDAX.WebsocketClient(url="wss://ws-feed.gdax.com", products="LTC-USD")

wsClient.start()
```

I am having trouble saving the results of `wsClient.start()`into a pandas dataframe. Not sure why records are not appending with this lines of code, can anyone please help me understand why not :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in wsClient.start():
    df1.append(wsClient.start())
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) you can see that it returns the resulting DataFrame, and doesn't alter the DataFrame on which `append` is called nor the DataFrame which is the argument.

In the body of your loop, you probably meant something like

```
    df1 = df1.append(wsClient.start())
```

As DJK correctly notes below, for a more efficient alternative, you can first create a list of all DataFrames, then append:

```
dfs = []
for i in wsClient.start():
    dfs.append(wsClient.start())
df1 = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: @DJK Thanks, you're right. Added a more efficient alternative.

Comment: Ami, I have been trying the code you posted plus the code @DJK created. None seem to work. When I run your code, a brief error message is created: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Not sure why nothing is getting appended.

Comment: Ami, I have to manually close the websocket connection, do you think that code be causing the lack of appending?

Comment: I don’t know, but looking at your code more closely,, it seems strange for another reason. You’re calling’start’ and iterating on the results. In each iteration, you’re appending the results of ‘start’ again. Are you sure that this is your intention?

Comment: Ami, that is not my intention. Novice with websocket. My intention is that I turn on the websocket and get new records. This websocket connects into exchange so I am looking for new rates continuously that I want to append.